# How to make plotly marker labels in scatter3d plots the same color as the marker?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

The label colors on my plotly 3d scatter charts do not match the marker colors:
[image]

All labels end up being the same color with the following minimal example:

```
plot_ly(
     data      = mtcars,
     type      = "scatter3d",
     mode      = "markers",
     colors    = c("blue","red"),
     text      = row.names(mtcars),
     hoverinfo = "text",
     color     = ~cyl,
     x         = ~disp,
     y         = ~hp,
     z         = ~qsec
)
```

With 2D scatter plots, the labels are colored appropriately:
[image]
[image]

Which is achieved using:

```
plot_ly(
     data      = mtcars,
     type      = "scatter",
     mode      = "markers",
     colors    = c("blue","red"),
     text      = row.names(mtcars),
     hoverinfo = "text",
     color     = ~cyl,
     x         = ~disp,
     y         = ~hp
)
```

I know a color range for the legend isn't appropriate in this example, but it's needed for the actual data I would use with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that if you set `color = ~as.factor(cyl)` it works correctly.

But I really don't have idea why.

The code:

```
plot_ly(
  data      = mtcars,
  type      = "scatter3d",
  mode      = "markers",
  colors    = ~c("blue","red"),
  text      = row.names(mtcars),
  hoverinfo = "text",
  color     = ~as.factor(cyl),
  x         = ~disp,
  y         = ~hp,
  z         = ~qsec
)
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: How would you change the size of the text labels?

Comment: Hi @Adel, give a look in the parameter `font`, this question may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114840/how-can-i-modify-label-size-in-plotly-r